# Wordpress Nested Shortcode. Attributes get truncated

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I have this code that I made for wordpress inside functions.php

```php
function card_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
    $attributes = shortcode_atts( array(
        'titolo' => '',
        'prezzo'  =>  '0',
        'bullet' => ''
    ), $atts );
    $title = esc_attr($attributes['titolo']);
    $price = esc_attr($attributes['prezzo']);
    $bullet =  esc_attr($attributes['bullet']);
 $output = '<div class="card">
    <div class="card_main_point">
        [card_title titolo="'.$title.'"]
        [card_price prezzo="'.$price.'€"]
    </div>
    <div class="card_secondary_point">
        <ul class="bullet_holder">
        [card_bullet bullet="'.$bullet .'"]
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
[card_style]';

 return do_shortcode($output);
}
```

I tried looking for answer in the internet but got no result as the output that comes out is this

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card_main_point">[card_titleTest][card_price42€]
        <div class="card_price">
            <h4></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card_secondary_point">
        <ul class="bullet_holder">[card_bulletrew;tre;ytr]
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried this solution but with the same outcome. It's like that shortcode that have attributes get trucated and only the variable remains. Can someone help me?

```php
function card_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
$attributes = shortcode_atts( array(
'titolo' => '',
'prezzo'  =>  '0',
'bullet' => ''
), $atts );
$title = esc_attr($attributes['titolo'];
$price = esc_attr($attributes['prezzo'];
$bullet =  esc_attr($attributes['bullet'];
$output = '<div class="card">
    <div class="card_main_point">'
        . do_shortcode('[card_title titolo="'.$title.'"]') . ''
        . do_shortcode('[card_price prezzo="'.$price.'€"]') .'
    </div>
    <div class="card_secondary_point">
        <ul class="bullet_holder">'
            . do_shortcode('[card_bullet bullet="'.$bullet .'"]') . '
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
'
. do_shortcode("[card_style]");

return do_shortcode($output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved. I had to clean the cache and on my last 2 tries I accidentally update the them style instead of the theme functions. If it is of help the topmost solution works